# How to set a symfony form collective to default to null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jquery-select2, symfony-forms

I have a select2 field that is filled by the symfony form builder. The field is nullable/clearable but I would like to set it to default to null.

```
  ->add('rfaLabMapSecondaryRfa', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->customOptionsRepository->getRFAs(),
                'attr' => ['class' => 'select2_rfa'],
            ])
```

The twig HTML looks like this:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label fixed_select2_fields" style="display: block;" for="rfa_lab_map_rfaLabMapSecondaryRfa">Secondary RFA:</label>
                    <div id="secondary_rfa">
                    {{ form_widget(form.rfaLabMapSecondaryRfa) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried messing with it using jQuery but can't seem to get it to default to null. I've searched other posts and they say to add an option. Not sure how I can do that with pre-built form collectives. Thanks for the help in advance

```
$('.select2_rfa').select2({
        width: '100%',
        placeholder: 'No secondary RFA',
        allowClear: true
    })
```

Comment: The Type should manage this if you add the option required=false and a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by prepending to the select2 class in JQuery

```
    $('.select2_rfa').prepend('<option selected=""></option>').select2({
        width: '100%',
        placeholder: 'No secondary RFA',
        allowClear: true
    })
```

The empty option selected allows the form to start null and still offer all possible choices.